# Javascript Function Multiple Forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this program that a user inputs a invoice number and then ajax goes and fills in the serial number, dealer name, number and invoice amount.

There are not a static amount of invoices. For the purpose of this example there are two invoice divs But there could be more or less. I have named my forms and divs differently however when it comes to the inputs they have the same names and ids. If i have different ids which I think i need too, I am not sure how to reference them with one java script function

Code HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<script>
  function dealerinfo() {
      str= "detinv="+document.getElementById("detinv").value + "&dettype="+document.getElementById("dettype").value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 var splitResult = xmlhttp.response.split("/");
                 document.getElementById("detname").value=splitResult[0];
                 document.getElementById("detnum").value=splitResult[1];
                 document.getElementById("detamt").value=splitResult[2];
                 document.getElementById("detser").value=splitResult[3];

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "deallookup.php");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(str);

    return false;       
  }
</script>


<div class="newboxes"  id="newboxes1">  
<form action="self.php" method="post" id="supplierform1" name="supplierform1">
Type: <input type="text" name="dettype" id="dettype" class="dettype" value = "C" >
<br>
Invoice Number: <input type="text" name="detinv" id="detinv" class="detinv" onblur="dealerinfo();">
<br>
Dealer Name :<input type="text" name="detname" id="detname" class="detname" ">
<br>
Amount:<input type="text" name="detamt" id="detamt" class="detamt" ">
<br>
Serial Number :<input type="text" name="detser" id="detser" class="detser" ">
<br>
Dealer Number:<input type="text" name="detnum" id="detnum" class="detnum" ">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="subbut" value="Submit" id="subbut">
<br><br><br>


</form>
</div>

<div class="newboxes"  id="newboxes2">  
<form action="self.php" method="post" name="supplierform2">
Type: <input type="text" name="dettype" id="dettype" class="dettype" value = "C" >
<br>
Invoice Number: <input type="text" name="detinv" id="detinv" class="detinv" onblur="dealerinfo();">
<br>
Dealer Name :<input type="text" name="detname" id="detname" class="detname" ">
<br>
Amount:<input type="text" name="detamt" id="detamt" class="detamt" ">
<br>
Serial Number :<input type="text" name="detser" id="detser" class="detser" ">
<br>
Dealer Number:<input type="text" name="detnum" id="detnum" class="detnum" ">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="subbut" value="Submit" id="subbut">
<br><br><br>


</form>
</div>


<br>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE

```
<?
$db = "SalesView";
include("msiconnect.php");

if($_POST["dettype"]=='C'):
 $sql = "SELECT dba_name, dealer_no, serialno, balancedue from sales where invoiceno = ".$_POST["detinv"]."";
 $result = $link->query($sql);
 $r = $result->fetch_array();
 if($result->num_rows > 0):
  $dealerinfo =$r["dba_name"]."/".$r["dealer_no"]."/".$r["balancedue"]."/".$r["serialno"];
 else:
  $dealerinfo ="Invoice Number not Found";  
 endif;
endif;

if($_POST["dettype"]=='P'):
 $sql = "SELECT dba_name, dealer_no, total from parts where invoiceno = ".$_POST["detinv"]."";
 $result = $link->query($sql);
 $r = $result->fetch_array();
 if($result->num_rows > 0):
  $dealerinfo = $r["dba_name"]."/".$r["dealer_no"]."/".$r["total"];
 else:
  $dealerinfo = "Invoice Number not Found";
 endif;
endif;

echo $dealerinfo;



?>
```

Thanks I know this alot to look at. I am convinced I need different IDs in my forms however I don't know how to make my once function look for different IDS
Maybe something with this.

Thanks

Comment: Without looking at your code, "I don't know how to make my once function look for different IDs" - **don't**. Use classes instead of IDs. `<div class='data-c' ...` then you can ref by classname `$(".data-c")...` to get all matching classes. classnames don't need to be used only for styling, they can also be used to group similar elements or for selection (in this case). Personally, I prefix with `data-` so that it's clear it's a data indicator, not a style indicator, but that's just preference - doesn't matter what you call the class [this could all be completely irrelevant to your problem...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach to using classes would be to use `document.querySelectorAll` to target the field elements by name within the parent form. It's not tested so you might need to tinker with it - but it does remove the need for recurring ids which are not valid.

```
<script>
    function dealerinfo( event ) {
        var el=typeof(event.target)!='undefined' ? event.target : event.srcElement;
        var parent = el.parentNode;
        var str= "detinv="+parent.querySelectorAll('detinv')[0].value + "&dettype="+parent.querySelectorAll('dettype')[0].value;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
                cbdealerinfo.call( this, xmlhttp.response, parent );
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "deallookup.php");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(str);      
    }

    function cbdealerinfo(response,parent){
        /* parent will be the form */
        var splitResult = response.split("/");
        parent.querySelectorAll('detname')[0].value=splitResult[0];
        parent.querySelectorAll('detnum')[0].value=splitResult[1];
        parent.querySelectorAll('detamt')[0].value=splitResult[2];
        parent.querySelectorAll('detser')[0].value=splitResult[3];

        /* call the function to reset the fields */
        resetfields.call( this, parent );
    }

    function resetfields( parent ){
        var col=parent.querySelectorAll('input');
        for( var n in col ) if( col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ) col[n].value='';
    }

</script>
```

---

In the code sample above, the javascript function is attached as an `onblur` event handler for a particular ( or series of ) form element. The parent in the original code is the form ( the text input is contained within the form - thus form is the parent. )

If there was a table within the form, like this:

```
<div class='newboxes'>  
    <form action='self.php' method='post'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Type:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='dettype' class='dettype' value = 'C' ></td>
                <td>Invoice Number:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='detinv' class='detinv' onblur='dealerinfo(event)'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dealer Name:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='detname' class='detname' /></td>
                <td>Amount:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='detamt' class='detamt' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serial Number:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='detser' class='detser' /></td>
                <td>Dealer Number:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='detnum' class='detnum' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3>
                    <input type='submit' name='subbut' value='Submit'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

The parent node is the containing element, which is now a `td` and it's parent is `tr` and the parent of the table row is `table`

```
table -> tr -> td -> input[type='text']
Great Grandparent -> Grandparent -> Parent -> child
```

You MIGHT find that you need to also factor in the `tbody` tag when traversing this html, ie:

```
table -> tbody -> tr -> td -> input[type='text']
Great Great Grandparent -> Great Grandparent -> Grandparent -> Parent -> Child
```

So, within the javascript function `dealerinfo`, rather than `var parent = el.parentNode;` you would need to go up several parent levels to find the actual table element, something like:

```
var parent = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to javascript/jquery. So when i run this in debugger mode on IE i get a message saying Unable to get property 'target' of undefined or null reference on the like var el = typeof(event.target) I am wondering what that means. Thanks Ram

Comment: ah - I forgot to mention that in the html, when you call the function it should be like this: `onblur='dealerinfo(event)'`

Comment: Thanks what I thought haha. Well that took that error away, now this one.Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference. On the var str.  I did take the [0]s away and there were no more errors. However then the program didn't work the way i needed it to. So i am not sure its getting the value its supposed to. Thanks again

Comment: What i ended up doing is changing the querySelectorAll('.detinv') placing .s in front of everything and It worked! Thanks so much ram

Comment: There is, for each of the elements in each form apart from the submit button and the `detinv` element,  a spare quote which should be removed also. `<input type="text" name="detname" id="detname" class="detname" ">` should be `<input type="text" name="detname" id="detname" class="detname" />`

Comment: Would there be any reason if there was a table in the form that the function wouldnt work?

Comment: yes - because you would then need to take into account the parent is a table cell and would need to work your way up the dom tree to find the table and then use a reference to the table as the parent.

Comment: How exactly does one go about that?

Comment: I see from your code and the tags associated with the question that you are using jQuery - I have no doubt there will be some handly builtin method to traverse the dom like this in jQuery but sadly I cannot offer guidance there - perhaps someone else will be able to suggest a neat shortcut for you!

Comment: In the head i called jquery but my program isnt using any jquery i dont think. pretty sure its all javascript.

Comment: I got it figured out, I didnt need a tbody. The parentNode section you posted worked. Thank you very much good sir! I'd buy you a cookie if I could haha!

Comment: Hey Ram. In this scenario if I wanted to clear out the form after lets say doing a ajax function to insert that record into my database. I know I would do mostly the same code as the ajax function but on the return section the 

   if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
                cbdealerinfo.call( this, xmlhttp.response, parent );
            }

how would i clear out the form

by doing . 

parent.querySelectorAll('detname')[0].reset()

However when i do this the chrome debugger mode says that that isnt a valid function. Thanks

Comment: `reset()` is not something I'm familar with - try simply `parent.querySelectorAll('detname')[0].value='';`

Comment: so I would do that for each element name (ie detname)?. Or could i put the name of the form and set the value of the form to '' if that makes sense lol

Comment: Is there anyway to reset the parent level? Like if I wanted to display that on blu information in a different div?

Comment: No - the grandparent->parent->child ( etc ) relationship is fixed by the layout of the elements. If the layout were to change then the relationship would consequently then change. You can however elect to display the content of the ajax call in an element of your choosing- how you identify and target the elected html element ( `div` most likely ) depends on the layout chosen. You could use a centred div that has a z-index higher than everything else ~ like lightbox for example... the options are, if not exactly, nearly endless......